# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7182).

Comment: The ugliness of many ads *on this site* is disturbing.

Comment: @Raphael Feel free to post your own proposals!

Comment: Apparently we have a downvoting troll here ... apparently someone who complains about this and that but has nothing else to contribute, i.e. no ad by himself

Comment: uh, isn't it time for 2018?

Answer (score 41):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Answer (score 27):

[image: TeX Live - cross-platform TeX software]

Comment: OP says "Please do not add anything else to the body of the post" .. Maybe the "copied from last year" part should be a comment

Answer (score 24):

[image: TeX online documentation lookup system]

Answer (score 21):

[image: TEXample.net]

Comment: Recent update in December 2016, next update in the next few days. :-)

Answer (score 20):

[image: TeX Users Group (TUG)]

Answer (score 20):

[image: PGFPlots Plot example gallery]

Comment: With a few new plots also in 2017 and more in the queue to come.

Answer (score 17):

[image: CervanTeX: Spanish TeX Users Group]

Comment: Copied from last year.

Answer (score 16):

[image: UK TeX FAQ - Questions and answers about TeX]

Answer (score 14):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Answer (score 14):

[image: TeXblog - News and ideas about TeX]

Comment: Still blogging since 8 years. :-)

Answer (score 14):

[image: visit glossaries gallery]

Comment: Copied over from last year.

Answer (score 13):

[image: TeXstudio - LaTeX made comfortable]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Comment: I'm kind of disappointed that this command does not open the site. :D

Comment: Feature request time!

Answer (score 11):

[image: MiKTeX: LaTeX system for windows]

Comment: Copied from 2015 campaign

Answer (score 11):

[image: LaTeX Community Forum - Talk about TeX and LaTeX]

Comment: Upgrade in Nov 2016 with responsive theme, Feb 2017 [topic tagging](http://latex-community.org/forum/tags) re-implemented.

Answer (score 10):

[image: TeXwelt - Fragen und Antworten zu TeX auf Deutsch]

Answer (score 10):

[image: visit TeX.tips!]

Comment: Most posts by Tobi, some by me.

Comment: Nice site, I skimmed through it and learned some useful thing. But it would be better to have higher volume, maybe bi-weekly (excluding announcements)?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure! Tobi has a small hiatus, I blog at several sites but have few time these days. But tex.tips was intended to be for quick small posts when there's no time, so I will continue, and so will Tobi. You can join the blog as writer if you like. :-)

Answer (score 10):

[image: TeX talk - news and interviews]

Comment: Interviews of TeX.SE users and blog posts.

Comment: The image is not really readable, that makes a weird effect.

Comment: @Clément It was from a screenshot, I'll see how to make it better.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Gruppo Utilizzatori Italiani di TeX]

Comment: +1 for the P.S. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Un nome, una garanzia! LOL

Answer (score 9):

[image: TeX questions and answers in French]

Comment: Our French friends.

Answer (score 8):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from last year.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work as easily, there was some dirty trick how to push this through.

Comment: @yo': Not last year. Currently the server that provides the pictures is simply broken.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Mathematica syntax highlighter for LaTeX]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Comment: Who downvotes this?

Comment: This is most useful to people who write their documents in LaTeX and make some of the figures with Mathematica. It is most often used to achieve a consistent look between the two. Personally, I use it because I want top quality formula typesetting in my figure labels.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked: Who downvoted this? It's not really explainable...

Answer (score 6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 6):

[image: comp.text.tex TeX Usenet group]

Comment: @Martin -- thanks for edits; wasn't paying enough attention.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Plea for TikzEdt]

Comment: I don't know if I have done things right...

Comment: "The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI."

Comment: @Raphael do you know I can I do it with `convert` of ImageMagick?

Comment: I hope you don't mean `mogrify -resize "600x250"` because that will look like crap. You'll have to recreate something with the proper proportions. I suggest Inkscape (or, you known, LaTeX with `standalone`). You can then export to PNG. (From PDF to png: `convert -density 300 in.pdf -resize "600>x" out.png`; pick a higher density if necessary (and feasible with your RAM).

Comment: @Raphael I used `standalone` with `tikz` package and this command to convert the `.pdf`: `convert -background white -alpha remove -density 150 "myfile.pdf" -quality 100 "myfile.png"`. I'll redo it with the option you've told me, thank you!

Comment: @Raphael please check if now is good, if you could, thank you!

Comment: As long as the PDF does not has the correct ratio of width/height, it's not going to be pretty.

Answer (score 5):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Answer (score 2):

[image: LaTeX-шаблон для кандидатской диссертации и её автореферата (LaTeX template for russian PhD thesis)]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]