# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8048).

Comment: Whoever is interested in this: We have more good ads in [tag:community-ads] previous years. Copy over those you find good, maybe as community wiki.

Comment: @MartinSchröder An addition: I think it should be one ad post per project or link. For example, in 2016 we had 5 ad posts to the same TeX.SE chat room, just with different color and different joke but actually the same ad multiplied.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: Copied from 2017 and 2016: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7193/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6493/35864

Answer (score 23):

[image: TEXample.net]

Comment: TikZ examples, classics, but more interesting: the TeX community aggregator of recent blog posts from everywhere.

Answer (score 21):

[image: TeX Live - cross-platform TeX software]

Answer (score 21):

[image: The LaTeX Font Catalogue]

Comment: Copied from last year: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7587/35864

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for the edit. Is the source for the image available somewhere? I guess that would be a better attribution than the link to last year's version.

Comment: I’ve put everything at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l2ca3etad7iitmk/AAC3WSHCYt2EIRE-x1nNFGVZa?dl=0

Comment: @Thérèse Brilliant! Thank you very much.

Comment: The same Dropbox folder now contains the sources of the version with the new address of the Font Catalogue.

Comment: @Thérèse I'm not sure if the system allows two images per post. I have removed the old picture. Feel free to revert if you feel the `.dk` image needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 19):

[image: TeXwelt - Fragen und Antworten zu TeX auf Deutsch]

Comment: This site and other sites are supported by [DANTE e.V.](http://www.dante.de).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Gruppo Utilizzatori Italiani di TeX]

Comment: Copied from the last year.

Comment: could you give a English translation,if you don't mind (In the comment is sufficient ;))?

Comment: @Raaja "Would you like to ask a question but you can't speak English? Don't worry, there is the Forum of the Italian TeX Group. P.S. = egreg answers also there!"

Comment: Thanks for the translation ;)

Comment: @Raaja You're welcome!

Answer (score 16):

[image: The TeX User Group]

Comment: Copied from 2018.

Answer (score 16):

[image: DANTE e.V. - German language TeX users group]

Comment: Copied from 2016.

Answer (score 15):

[image: TeX questions and answers in French]

Comment: A growing community of French TeX friends thanks to the effort of Denis and Patrick and others.

Answer (score 15):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Comment: Image from https://tug.org/tug2019/tug2019-color.jpg, used with permission from TUG -- To be replaced with http://tug.org/art/welcome-bw.pdf after the conference.

Comment: Other possible image for the time after TUG19: https://www.tug.org/publicity/tfz_master/

Comment: Post TUG replacement image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2HMm.png

Comment: @Raaja The edit didn't conform to the form of the posts that is required for the software to pick up everything correctly, so I rolled it back for now. We should probably discuss where the new link should be going to (if it goes to TUG.org we have to ads for that site; several ads for the chat were discouraged this year), if the conference ad should be left online for a bit longer to lure people to the abstracts and the proceedings volume of TUGboat or should be deleted altogether after a while.

Comment: You can check if the image and links are picked up correctly at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8048

Comment: Replaced the conference ad with a generic TUG.org ad and the suggested replacement image.

Answer (score 13):

[image: LaTeX]

Comment: Copied from 2018.

Answer (score 11):

[image: TeX talk - news and interviews]

Comment: This is our TeX.SE blog http://tex.blogoverflow.com that moved to the new address.

Answer (score 11):

[image: TeX online documentation lookup system]

Comment: From 2017: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7205/35864

Answer (score 10):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from 2018.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Got content questions? Writing.SE can help!]

Comment: Hello.  I'm from Writing.SE, where technical/academic/scientific-writing questions are on-topic.  I thought there might be natural overlap between our sites; you provide outstanding answers about key tools, and we provide answers about how to write the content itself.  Thank you for considering our request.

Answer (score 9):

[image: visit the glossaries gallery]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 8):

[image: LaTeX Community Forum - Talk about TeX and LaTeX]

Comment: Disclosure: I maintain this forum and keep it as a discussion forum (as alternative support way to this strict Q&A site). I now host it as http://latex.org but this domain was way too expensive so not sure if it returns to http://latex-community.org anyway, so I kept the banner.

Answer (score 8):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Answer (score 8):

[image: 13th International ConTeXt Meeting]

Answer (score 6):

[image: LaTeX template for russian PhD thesis (LaTeX-шаблон для кандидатской диссертации и её автореферата)]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]