# Bounty Community Ad Error

Tags: support

I just saw a strange error in [one of the Community Promotion Ads](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8071/156344) – the ["active bounty" ad (`bounty.png`)](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/tex.stackexchange.com/bounty.png). Currently it looks like this

[image]

So, there are 1 active bounty which worth 0 reputation in total. Currently there is indeed one active bounty, but obviously it doesn't worth 0 reputation

[image]

Therefore, the "worth" number in the ad should be `+50` instead of `+`.

Is this a bug of the `bounty.png`?

Or it won't show the total reputations if that number is smaller than 100? – I think about this when I see that the `bounty.png`s of other sites are working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 11:05, 21 March 2019 (UTC time), I just have a [re-check](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/tex.stackexchange.com/bounty.png), and it is fixed:

[image]

However, I'm still looking forward to an explicit explanation.

Comment: [We (Stack Exchange) don't provide that ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291735/whats-the-official-stance-on-the-bounty-ad), so I have no visibility into what may have gone wrong there. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AdamLear thanks for the update. However, was that shrug emoticon really necessary? Considering that SE has not been exactly treating us the TeX.sx people fairly in the recent events [1](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue) [2](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code) [3](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/tex-new-site-theme-is-live) (to list a few), I would take that unfortunate reference as bad timing.

Comment: @PauloCereda I'm not sure what the emoticon came off as a reference to, but I apologize for any offense caused; it was absolutely not intended.